# Ошибка: This class should be public (android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarView.HomeView)

Tags: android

Пытаюсь выполнить в Eclipse :
Project settings -> Android Tools -> Export Signed Application Package

В Lint Warnings выдается следующая ошибка:

> This class should be public (android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarView.HomeView)
>
> Issue: Ensures that classes registered in the manifest file are instantiatable
> Id: Instantiatable
>
> Activities, services, broadcast receivers etc. registered in the manifest file must be >"instantiatable" by the system, which means that the class must be public, it must have >an empty public constructor, and if it's an inner class, it must be a static inner class.

Как ее исправить?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24595383 посмотрите вот этот ответ.